# is static library with Objective C compatible with any version of XCode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, compiler-version

I am from c++ background and in c++ world, if I create an static library with any specific version of a compiler, then it is advisable to use same version of compiler for binary which will use this static library.

Is this statement true for Objective C static library as well? or if I have Objective C static library compiled with XCode X & and executable compiled with XCode Y still there will be no conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Yes no conflicts. Migration of my legacy project on `Objective-C` to Xcode 12 was done without problems: just opened and compiled. Despite my colleagues: they had to continue working with Xcode 10 and 11 on swift projects.

Objective-C is ABI, Module and Source stable language like C, despite C++ and Swift